# heap vs data segment vs stack allocation

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory

Am looking at the following program and not sure how the memory is allocated and why:

```
void function() {
    char text1[] = "SomeText";
    const char* text2 = "Some Text";
    char *text = (char*) malloc(strlen("Some Text") + 1 );
}
```

In the above code, the last one is obviously in the heap. However, as I understand `text2` is in the data segment of the program and `text1` may be on the stack. Or is my assumption wrong? What is the right assumption here? Is this compiler dependent?

Comment: +1 : very intersting question

Comment: do you understand the difference between the pointer and the data it points to?

Comment: Yes n0rd, however this one struck me as it seems like this one has multiple possible choices..

Comment: This makes a nice interview question :)

Comment: `text1`, `text2` and `text` are themselves on the stack. But `"..."`s are in text segment. Allocated memory obtained from `malloc` is in heap.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
// Array allocated on the stack and initialized with "SomeText" string.
// It has automatic storage duration. You shouldn't care about freeing memory.
char text1[] = "SomeText"; 

// Pointer to the constant string "Some Text".
// It has static storage duration. You shouldn't care about freeing memory.
// Note that it should be "a pointer to const".
// In this case you'll be protected from accidential changing of 
// the constant data (changing constant object leads to UB).
const char* text2 = "Some Text";

// malloc will allocate memory on the heap. 
// It has dynamic storage duration. 
// You should call "free" in the end to avoid memory leak.
char *text = (char*) malloc(strlen("Some Text") + 1 );
```

Comment: What happens if you cast away the constness from `text2` and try to modify it? Is this a segfault?

Comment: Yes. That would result in a segfault.

Comment: @DrewNoakes it is undefined behavior. It could be segfault, but you cannot count on it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you are right, on most systems:

`text1` will be a writable variable array on stack (it is required to be a writable array)

`text2` has to be `const char*` actually, and yes, it will point to a text segment of the executable (but that might change across executable formats)

`text` will be on heap